# Laravel 4: Will a soft delete on a table also apply to it relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table called *'Titles'* and i am going to add soft deletes to it but it also has several other tables that reference this 'Titles' table:

Currently if i delete a title it will automatically removed at title details form all other tables referenced.

So if i add a soft delete to the *'Titles'* table when a delete is performed will it then do a soft delete on the *'titles'* table but will remove the details from the referenced tables?
Or will it ignore the onDelete Cascade request and leave the referenced data alone?

If the first option then will i need to add a **$table->softDeletes();** to all tables ref. as well as adding the protected **$softDelete = true;** to their models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't. You have to apply softDeletes on relations too (see the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting))
It can't be propagated with a `ON DELETE CASCADE` because soft deleted is a property of Laravel, not MySQL or something else.

But when you will load your model, Laravel won't load soft deleted model and its relations.
So a unique soft deleted would be sufficient.

Comment: Thats what i thought it just that if its not actually deleting but adding a values then the propagated request using on delete cascade should then really not activate as its not a deletion? Thanks for this probably best to try and see

Comment: In fact i just added the soft delete to the titles table and because its adding a value to a field and not a delete it ignores the whole delete relationship request. cool thanks again @AlexKevler

Comment: Having the same problem today1